# Outlook custom task pane control

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, visual-studio-addins

I'm developing an outlook addin that has a button in a custom task pane (that's in an inspector window). When its clicked, I'd like it to do something to the current active item (in my case, it's the appointmentItem). I've tried this (this code is in the custom task pane class):

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Outlook.Inspector inspector = (Outlook.Inspector)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector;
        Outlook.AppointmentItem appt = (Outlook.AppointmentItem)inspector.CurrentItem;
        appt.Body += "this is a test";
    }
```

but it through me this error:

> Cannot convert method group 'ActiveInspector' to non-delegate type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector'. Did you intend to invoke the method?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think ActiveInspector is a method & not a property.

Try this 

Outlook.Inspector inspector = (Outlook.Inspector)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector**()**;